# Is it possible to use intellij as my editor when using git on the command line?

Tags: windows, git, intellij-idea

I'm learning git from the command line and I'm not too familiar with vim (my default editor).  On the other hand I'm extremely comfortable and productive within Intellij IDEA.  I was wondering if it's possible to use intellij as an editor when I run commands like `git commit` (note I didn't add a `-m`) or `git rebase -i`?

I'm on Windows 7, how can I use Intellij's editor as the git editor?  I tried using idea.exe as the GIT_EDITOR, but it gave me errors whenever it would try to start it.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to use SourceTree which is very easy and fast to use for any project.

Then on Intellij IDEA you have a full integration on some git repo like on github --> http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/committing-changes-to-a-local-git-repository.html